# Monitoring third party API calls using Prometheus

Tags: spring-boot, monitoring, prometheus

In my spring boot application, I'm consuming third party public APIs. I want to monitor this third party API calls, total number of API hits, total number of success responses and number of error responses. I have already added micrometer Prometheus dependency `micrometer-registry-prometheus-1.1.3`

In which way I can get custom API monitoring ?